# Ctrl+space is not working in Spring Tool suite

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, spring-tool-suite

Ctrl + Space is not working in Spring tool suite 3.7.3 but it was working not sure what went wrong, Could anyone please guide me to get work that.

When i try to do that i am getting Error message says"No Completions Available"

Tried this below solution still its not working
Configure Eclipse’s content assist, go “Preferences>Java>Editor>Content Assist>Advanced“. Make sure “Other Java Proposals” is ticked
[image]

Comment: Which is your operating system / window manager? I suppose that something else captured Ctrl + Space before Spring Tools Suite.

Comment: Perhaps it is a rogue .java file is being edited without classpath etc. Can you create a Java project in STS via the wizard, create a simple class with a main method and check if you get content assist in that class.

Comment: Can you show us a print screen of your preferences in "Preferences>Java>Editor>Content Assist>Advanced" ?

Comment: @Alex- Please refer printscreen

Comment: @aboyko : Yes as you said i am getting content assist for Java Project but not for Spring Project , still i am not able resolve when i have Spring Project

Comment: How do you create Spring project? What is the use case for CA in java file from Spring project? Where exactly are you invoking CA and what are the expected proposals? As a side thing you may try disabling Code Recommenders in the preferences... perhaps that makes the difference.

Comment: @aboyko: Created a Spring Starter project , I am trying to use CA in all my Controller, Service and DAO classes

Answer (score 0):

It is quite old post but I stumbled on same issue and from the first screenshot I tried something below that worked for me. I checked all the Java related checkboxes (“Preferences>Java>Editor>Content Assist>Advanced“) and it started working. Hope it helps!
[image: preference]

Answer (score -1):

Try to update STS from Help -> Check for updates.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtEUT.png)
Wait until update complete. you can check update progress in Progress view(Window->Show View -> Progress)
Once update complete restart STS.
If Java version updated need to change SpringToolSuite4.ini file as below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48oXe.png)

After above changes, ctrl+space is working in application.properties file.